# how to access embedded arrays that is loaded asynchronously

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

[image: https://gyazo.com/e80eea9f69c0cbb52cc7929d0a46ea2f]

Name of Object is totalCount 
How do I access count from above?
I tried:
`Object.result` and it's coming out undefined

Second attempt:

```
var count = totalCount.result;
for(var i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
  console.log(count[i])
  // no 'length' property of undefined
}
```

I totally have no problem accessing this totalCount with angular

```
<div ng-repeat="num in totalCount.result">
  {{ num.count }} // returns 1
</div>
```

==========================My Answer========================================
@Norguard mentioned that retrieving data asynchronously will have some implications with loading in the data. So, I put my data in a promise:

```
exports.totalCount = function ($http) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $http.get('/api/count')
                    .success(function (data) {
                        resolve(data)
                    })
                    .error(function (err) {
                        reject(err)
                    })
    })
}
```

this is the draft of my controller:

```
exports.countController = function ($scope, $http, totalCount) {
    var c = totalCount.then(function(data) {
        console.log(data[0].count)
    })
}
```

Comment: Could you copy the code where you log the object (first image)? Also, don't use Object as a variable. Object is already defined in native javascript.

If you are using angular it's likely that you have an "Object" variable inside the controller's scope (something like scope.Object.result), which is different from Object.result

Comment: I think Object might be a reserved word in JavaScript. Not sure why it works in angular though...

Comment: What variable are you `console.log()`ing to get that Object in the inspector?

Comment: Sorry about that. I just used object for representation. The name of the object is actually totalCount.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I want to acces count within result Array

Comment: show where you assign this object to `$scope.Object`.The word `Object` is a console description it can't be the name of a variable

Answer (score 0):

If the variable name of the Object is `totalCount`, then

```
totalCount.result[0].count
```

will return the `count` of `1` from the object example you've shown.

Here's how this works:

1. `totalCount` is the object.
2. `result` is an array, with 1 item in the example you've shown.
3. `[0]` is the first (and only) item in the `result` array.
4. `count` is the property you want.

So `totalCount.result[0].count` gets the `count` property, from the `0`th item in the `result` array from the `totalCount` object.

Comment: totalCount.result.length ????

Comment: If you wanted to get the number of items in `totalCount.result`, then `totalCount.result.length` would work. If you want to access the `count` property within `totalCount > result > count`, then `totalCount.result[0].count` is what you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
totalCount.result[0].count;
```

But that depends on *when* you're trying to access it and how you're using it.

Comment: it still says 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined'. Right now I'm just logging it directly into the console. totalCount is loaded from a service that retrieves my counts. does that have some implications?

Comment: @ken it does if you're loading it asynchronously, and you're trying to access/log it prior to actually retrieving it in a later call-stack.

Comment: thanks man! I figured it out.